# How to use hash_map in C++ for string key and int value

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl, hashmap

Can someone give an example how to use hash_map in C++ with string as a key and integer as a value?
Is something like hash_map h; 
a valid syntax? Do I explicitly have to define a hashing function or there is a predifined one for string keys?

Comment: Use std::unordered_map, not hash_map.

Comment: I know about it, but I want to be able to compile on compilers that do not support c++11. I participate in algorithms contests and I cant be sure that the test environments support the standart

Comment: C++11 has `std::unordered_map`, TR1 has `std::tr1::unordered_map`, Boost has `boost::unordered_map`. If the test environment supports neither, you'd have to implement your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation [here](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/hash_map.html), the example shown uses strings as keys and int as values (sometimes it is better to just check the docs first then ask here on so : D).

To be more precise:

- you have to specify the key type, the value type, a hash function and a comparison function in the template
- you can either construct your own hash function or use a default functor provided by the libs by instantiating a template for [hash](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/hash.html)
- for accessing the values just use the keys as if they were the index of an array

(I'm not pasting the code, you can find it in the documentation)

Comment: Do you think the test environment will happen to have technology as outdated as the STL installed?

Comment: I do not know, I was sticking to the question desiderata : ) (Btw the story is the same, just check the documentation first)